# Getting a css height value from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So currently I have a div that houses an image. The css is setup as so

```
.InnerBanner{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.InnerBanner img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

and since the outer container no longer sees the height as anything i have to use jquery to load the height after the fact and it is an obvious switch on the page. I was wondering if there is either a way to do this soley in css or a way to do this before the page loads in jquery. I've exhausted search engines trying to find a way to do this. Odds are I'm not phrasing it right but hey you win some and you lose some.

the jquery for loading is below

```
function Height(){
    var height = $(".BannerImage").height();
    var em = height/200;
    var newfont = em * 24;  
    $(".InnerBanner a").css("font-size", newfont);
    $(".InnerBanner").height($(".BannerImage").height());
}
```

the function is currently called like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML so that we can see how everything is fit together?

Comment: you dont want to use jquery ?

Comment: let me knw if my answer works or you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to call jquery on document load so it actually loads the image so you can get it's height. On document ready the image will not be loaded(depending on the size, butt 99% it will not be fully loaded). Because of position absolute the image does not take any space in it's parent, so it behaves like a totally independent element.

So to do it with jQuery :

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('.InnerBanner').height( $('.InnerBanner img').height() );
});
```

Also, as I can see from the css .InnerBanner img will take up the complete width of it's parent element, so why do you add position:absolute to the image?

Comment: there are more than one each with it's own z-element to fade in and out of existance

Comment: Are they all the same width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking to do this in CSS,

```
.InnerBanner{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.InnerBanner img{
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

<!--Same height and width for both class-->
.InnerBanner img,
.InnerBanner{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

other trick is [here](http://www.codelord.net/2013/11/18/css-tip-divs-with-equal-dynamic-heights/)

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="columns-container">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
</div>





.layout {
    display: table;
}

.layout .columns-container {
    display: table-row;
}

.layout .columns-container .column {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

> Since we don’t know the columns’ heights, we can’t set a fixed height
>   on their parent. Also setting height: 100% or something like that on
>   the columns won’t work: we are counting on them to spread to the
>   maximum height and thus make their parent taller.

In your case

```
.InnerBanner{
   display: table-row;
}

.InnerBanner img{
   display: table-cell;
}

.InnerBannerlayout {
   display: table;
}
```

keep an extra layout parent div with class `InnerBannerlayout .`

Comment: was this ans helpful ?